# Can someone explain this block of python code for me line by line

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import pywinauto
    desktop = pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia")
    window = desktop.windows(title_re=".* Google Chrome$",control_type="Pane")[0]

    wrapper_list = window.descendants(control_type="TabItem")

    for wrapper in wrapper_list:
         print(wrapper.window_text())
```

I got this code from [Get urls of opened tabs in browser pywinauto python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594066/get-urls-of-opened-tabs-in-browser-pywinauto-python)

I'd like to know how each line of code works, If anyone could kindly explain this to me  it would be much appreciated.Specially on the
window.descendants(control_type="TabItem")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wrapper_list = window.descendants(control_type="TabItem")
```

---

This will return only the list of open tab names..

```
["uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Can someone .... line - Stack Overflow - Brave', Pane",uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Downloads', TabItem]
```

---

It also returns pane also (opened browser)

Suppose if you dont provide any parameter like:

```
wrapper_list = window.descendants()
```

Every thing will come which ever present in browser but Excepts contents in browser.

Including bookmarks list ( but some times you will get browser conrtents also but sometimes not)

which looks like stackoverflow website.

```
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Why not use the same distribution for the prior in 
Bayesian statistics?', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Was Cain let off too lightly for murder, according to 
the biblical account?', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'What does "Danger!" mean?', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Proof of a neat pattern in polynomials', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'macOS, the command line developer tool missing after 
updated to Monterey 12.6', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - ' Question feed', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - '', GroupBox
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Stack Overflow', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - '', GroupBox
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'STACK OVERFLOW', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Questions', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Help', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'PRODUCTS', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Teams', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Advertising', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Collectives', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Talent', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'COMPANY', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'About', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Press', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Work Here', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Legal', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Privacy Policy', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Terms of Service', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Contact Us', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Cookie Settings', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Cookie Policy', Hyperlink
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Technology', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Culture & recreation', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Life & arts', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Science', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Professional', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Business', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'API', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Data', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Blog', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Facebook', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Twitter', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'LinkedIn', Hyperlink
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Instagram', Hyperlink
uia_controls.StaticWrapper - 'Site design / logo © 2022 Stack Exchange Inc; user 
contributions licensed under ', Static
uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'CC BY-SA', Hyperlink
uia_controls.StaticWrapper - '. ', Static
uia_controls.StaticWrapper - 'rev 2022.9.16.42980', Static
######################
for wrapper in wrapper_list:
    print(wrapper) #
```

So if you use
wrapper_list = window.descendants(control_type="MenuItem")
you will get MenuItem ... Here
uia_controls.MenuItemWrapper - 'Search tabs', MenuItem

MenuItem is control_Type

Finally it is used to filter out the contents.

If you nees current working pane just use "Pane".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done. See inline notes I made below.

```
import pywinauto # imports the pywinauto lib

 # collects the active windows on the users desktop.
desktop = pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia") 

# search currently open windows for the regex string and return the first one
# the regex string targets open google chrome browser windows
window = desktop.windows(title_re=".* Google Chrome$",control_type="Pane")[0]


# return a list of open tabs in the browser
wrapper_list = window.descendants(control_type="TabItem")


for wrapper in wrapper_list:  # iterate through the tab list 
    print(wrapper.window_text())   # and print the tab title for each tab
```